# Получить и сравнить все объекты одного пользователя

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, foreach

Доброе утро! Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему с которой борюсь уже 3 день.

Есть 4 таблицы — *Owner, Cars, Dealer, Reviews*

```
Owner
id | firstname |  lastname  |
---|-----------|------------|
1  |   Jonny   |  Lanbergs  |
2  |    Mark   |   Larsen   |

Cars
cid | title | ownerid | type |
----|-------|---------|------|
30  | Name  |    1    |  car |
40  | Name  |    1    |  car |

Dealer
did | title | ownerid |  type |
---|-------|---------|--------|
30 | Name  |    2    | dealer |
50 | Name  |    1    | dealer |

Reviews
id |  review  | itemid  |  type  |
---|----------|-------- |--------|
1  |  Hello   |   30    |   car  |
2  |  Salut   |   30    | dealer |
3  |  Hola    |   40    |   car  |
4  |  Hola    |   50    | dealer |


id - id отзыва/пользователя
cid - id объекта Cars
did - id объекта Dealer
title - название объекта
ownerid - id владельца
review - отзыв
itemid - id объекта для которого написан отзыв
type - тип объекта
```

В начале необходимо получить все объекты одного пользователя. Далее исходя из полученных данных, получить все отзывы к объектам данного пользователя.

К примеру, нужно получить объекты пользователя Jonny (ID = 1). Вначале делаем запрос к двум таблицам (Cars и Dealer). После выполнения запроса получаем 3 объекта:

*— Cars (ID 30)*

*— Cars (ID 40)*

*— Dealer (ID 50)*

**Итого:** 30, 40, 50

После делаем запрос к таблице *Reviews* и выводим все отзывы у которых *itemid* равняется *30, 40, 50*.
Но тут возникает проблема. В таблице *Reviews*, есть еще одно значение *itemid - 30* (объект принадлежащий другому пользователю). В итоге мы получим все отзывы, даже принадлежащие объекту другого пользователя *Mark (ID = 2)*.

Каким образом можно сравнить что полученные значения *30, 40, 50*, относятся к типам *30 - car, 40 - car, 50 - dealer*. Что в данном запросе второй *ID 30* не может отображаться т.к. он относится к типу *dealer*, а полученное текущее значение *30* относится к типу *car*.

Запрос:

```
$user = $this->data['userid'];
$reviews = array();

// получаем объекты из Cars
$this->db->select('cid');
$this->db->where('ownerid', $user);
$cget = $this->db->get('cars')->result();
foreach($cget as $c){
    array_push($reviews, $c->cid);
}

// получаем объекты из Dealer
$this->db->select('did');
$this->db->where('ownerid', $user);
$dget = $this->db->get('dealer')->result();
foreach($dget as $d){
    array_push($reviews, $d->did);
}

if(!empty($reviews)){
    foreach($reviews as $id){
        $this->db->or_where('itemid', $id); // сравниваем itemid с полученными объектами
    }
}

$this->db->order_by('id','desc');
return $this->db->get('reviews')->result(); // получаем и выводим результат
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вначале... после... зачем? всё делается одним запросом.

```
SELECT r.itemId
     , r.review
     , r.type
     , COALESCE(c.title,d.title) title
     , COALESCE(o1.id,o2.id) oid
     , COALESCE(o1.firstname,o2.firstname) firstname
     , COALESCE(o1.lastname,o2.lastname) lastname
FROM      Reviews r
LEFT JOIN Dealer  d  ON r.itemId  = d.did AND r.type = d.type
LEFT JOIN Owner   o1 ON d.ownerId = o1.id
LEFT JOIN Cars    c  ON r.itemId  = c.cid AND r.type = c.type
LEFT JOIN Owner   o2 ON c.ownerId = o2.id
/* WHERE COALESCE(o1.id,o2.id) = 1 */ 
HAVING oid = 1
;
```

Comment: Делал с использование Join одним запросом, но суть получалась такая же. Сейчас попробую ваш вариант, чуть позже отпишусь. Спасибо.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Благодаря Вам, все получилось. Не хватало в запросе $this->db->having.

Comment: Having тут использован исключительно для того, чтобы можно было ссылаться на имя поля выходного набора. Можно было вместо этого написать условие отбора как в комментарии.